# Preparation for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS home server

Tags: networking, server, ssh, dns

I just setup Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server Edition on my home lab PC. My Internet ISP provide me with dynamic public ip address, and I use freedns.afraid.org to update record for my public IP address.

I set Static LAN IP 192.168.0.200 for my server, and I'd like to have my subdomain point to my home server. How to properly setup FQDN for my system? I did use `$ sudo hostname set-hostname server.example.com`. Is that enough? I saw somewhere I also need to edit `/etc/hosts`. I have no clue what and where should I edit.

```
/etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 ubuntu-server
192.168.0.200 server.example.com
```

Is this the correct setting? I plan to install some Control Panel. Hope anyone can point me to the right direction. Thank you.